# R select first appearance of a value

Tags: r, filtering, state-machine

I need to select specific values in a dataset in R and can't figure out how to actually do it.

(As a sidenote: What does the data represent?)

This is a measurement of a network node connecting to three other nodes.
'time' represents a relative time, (when did something happen).
'tm1,tm2,tm3' shows in which protocol state the connection is currently.
'known' is the absolute number of nodes which should be connected. (here max 3)

First of all some test data as csv:

```
time,tm1,tm2,tm3,known
4,1,0,0,1
12,2,0,0,2
206,3,0,0,3
238,2,1,0,3
255,1,2,0,3
297,1,1,1,3
309,1,0,2,3
401,0,1,2,3
446,0,0,3,3
3,1,0,0,1
58,2,0,0,2
235,1,1,0,2
258,1,0,1,2
320,0,1,1,2
335,0,0,2,2
874,1,0,2,3
1024,0,1,2,3
1030,0,0,3,3
3,1,0,0,1
20,2,0,0,2
132,1,1,0,2
151,1,0,1,2
207,0,1,1,2
228,0,0,2,2
852,1,0,2,3
929,0,1,2,3
938,0,0,3,3
```

Each line means "something" has changed in the system, but I have to filter this data.
E.g one frame is:

```
time,tm1,tm2,tm3,known
 3,1,0,0,1  <- ignore
20,2,0,0,2  <- ignore
132,1,1,0,2 <- ignore
151,1,0,1,2 <- select  (first appearance of 1 in tm3)
207,0,1,1,2 <- ignore
228,0,0,2,2 <- select  (first appearance of 2 in tm3)
852,1,0,2,3 <- ignore
929,0,1,2,3 <- ignore
938,0,0,3,3 <- select  (first appearance of 3 in tm3)
```

The selected data contains always 3 interesting entries and each "frame" holds 9 lines, this is true for all so called frames (you can notice that when the time jumps to a lesser value in the csv data)

Maybe I need to plot more data, but this gets even more complicated and I'm not sure how I can plot such a state machine correctly. Running with 3 "nodes" is surely manageable with conditions, but as soon as I need to do that for lets say 6 Nodes, this runs surely out of hand. I'm relative new in R and so I'm not sure if R is the right decision, I just wanted to quickly plot some measurement data and therefor R fits perfectly. 
But how much work is it to plot such state machines in R properly, I think I cannot invest so much time in it and just run with simple data plotting.

Unfortunately, I cannot estimate how complicated it will get.
Maybe someone can enlighten me or did already visualize a state machine and has some tips how to do it.

A bit more detail on visualizing the states:

Suggest there are 3 nodes in a network, which should be connected. So each line represents actually a change in the network connection state.

The protocol which is executed consists of three protocol stages, which needs to be executed for a connection.

So e.g. a line like:

```
4,1,0,0,1
```

means, there was a message received from a node, now proceed in the protocol.
A following line is then:

```
100,0,1,0,1
```

If this stage succeeds, the next protocol stage happens:

```
200,0,0,1,1
```

If we reach this state, the other node is authenticated, verified and connected.
As you can see in my example data, these messages appear not in any ordered ways.
Although there is never a transition between:

```
4,1,0,0,1
```

directly to

```
200,0,0,1,1
```

messages from other nodes can appear in between any other message.

The interesting part of this is actually not the visualization, but the time it takes for each protocol stage transition. This is the data I actually need to get.

As I write this, I think with the actual data it is not possible to visualize this with  the current information.

An easy way could be, introduce an unique identifier for each node and sort the list based on identifier and time. Then we automatically get a somewhat ordered list, because no protocol stage can be jumped over for a single node, so it is ordered correctly based on time. Because there are fixed entries for each node itself these data could be easily calculated and visualized, I guess.

I currently see no other way, the problem is, this data is not so easily achievable, but if I need to visualize it, it seems i cannot get over the unique identifiers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with statemachine(s), but does your question boil down to selecting the first row for each time the values in `tm3` change? Or is there more to it?

Comment: yes, this is the main part of my current problem.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/9126/implement-state-machine-pattern-using-s4-class) you can find an approach using state machine pattern via S4 class from R, that may you help in designing your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `diff()` function and some logical indexing to get the first row each time there is a non zero difference in the column of choice. For example, assuming your data is in a data.frame named `dat`:

```
> dat[c(dat$tm3[1], diff(dat$tm3)) != 0,]
   time tm1 tm2 tm3 known
6   297   1   1   1     3
7   309   1   0   2     3
9   446   0   0   3     3
10    3   1   0   0     1
13  258   1   0   1     2
15  335   0   0   2     2
18 1030   0   0   3     3
19    3   1   0   0     1
22  151   1   0   1     2
24  228   0   0   2     2
27  938   0   0   3     3
```

Try running this part by itself to see the booleans created: `c(dat$tm3[1], diff(dat$tm3)) != 0`

The code above will not return the first row, but if you need that - change the boolean indexing to this instead: `dat[c(TRUE, diff(dat$tm3)) != 0,]`

This was also answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/fast-ways-in-r-to-get-the-first-row-of-a-data-frame-grouped-by-an-identifier/7889#7889) on crossValidated.

Comment: looks really good thank you. I let the question open a little bit, maybe I get a response to my other question. Thank you very much!

Comment: @evildead - Can you expand a bit on the second part of your question, i.e. the visualization of the statemachine? Do you need to visualize each column independently of one another? Jointly? Over time (or implied time by row)?

Comment: I'll add some more info on that.